# Square matrix A is singular $\iff \operatorname{rank}(A)<n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that if a matrix is not of a full rank than it is singular, but is it always true that singular matrices are of non-full ranks?

Answer (score 3):

Using rank theorem,
$$n=\dim \ker A+\dim Rg(A).$$
Therefore,
$$\text{Singular} \implies \ker A\neq \{0\}\implies \dim\ker A\geq 1$$
$$\implies  n-\dim\ker(A)\leq n-1\implies \dim Rg(A)<n.$$

Comment: I know that $\operatorname{rank}(A)<n$ means that $\ker \not= {0}$, but how do you get from singular (which as far as I understand means that there is no $A^{-1}$ such that $AA^{-1}=I$ to $\ker\not = 0$?

Comment: I've just made it (i.e. singular $\implies $ not full rank). How can this very easy proof can be not clear ? (it's difficult to make it easier since it's already very natural...) @PanthersFan92